# PHPUnit CakePHP 4.X - mock up the identity object, but how?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-4.x

i written a webaplication with cakephp 4.x. In my controller(AppController.php) i have implements the following:

```
...
public function beforeRender(\Cake\Event\EventInterface  $event)
{

    #Load User_ID
    if($this->Authentication->getIdentity()){
        $identity = $this->Authentication->getIdentity();
        $user_id = $this->Authentication->getIdentity()->getIdentifier();
    } 

}
...
```

Now i written the phpunit test following:

```
...
private function loginAsAdmin() {
    $this->Users = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Users');
    $user = $this->Users->get(1);
    $this->session(['Auth.User'=> $user->toArray()]);
}
/**
 * Test loginAsUser method
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testLoginAsAdmin(): void
{
    $this->loginAsAdmin();
    
    $this->get('/admin/dashboard');
    
    $this->assertSession(1, 'Auth.User.id'); //check if the user is logged in
}
...
```

But my identity object is allways empty.

[image: empty identity object]

The object should actually look like this:

[image: the original object with data]

i have no more ideas how to implement it. Can someone help me? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the authentication plugin, users are by default stored as objects, if you pass anything other than an object that implements `\ArrayAccess`, then the authentication service will wrap the given data in an instance of `\ArrayObject`.

Also the data is by default expected to be stored at the `Auth` key, not `Auth.User`.

Theoretically passing array data should work too (as in "being treated as authenticated and data being set in the identity object"), even when nested in an additional key (unless you've enabled the `identify` option for the session authenticator), so maybe there's additional problems somewhere in your code, the fact that there's keys like `storage` and `_config` in the array object is really weird, that shouldn't happen in an out of the box setup.

Anyways, normally you'd test with authentication like this:

```php
$user = $this->Users->get(1);
$this->session(['Auth' => $user]);
```

See also

- **[Authentication Cookbook > Testing with Authentication](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/testing.html)**

Comment: Thanks @ndm for your help. It is really appreciated. I have also added my vote to your answer. :)